# Stitching multiple meshes and aligning vertices

Tags: unity

I am generating a map in unity, and i am stuck with a specific issue.

Due to the 64xxxk vertices restriction on unity I need to generate a map in sections.

I generate a noisemap of x times the 240x240 as seen below: 
[image: Tile Mape]

I then generate 9 tiles, and i grab the height from the noise map, based on the position of the tile, but for some reason the edges does not align properly.

[image]

The spacing is correct, if you view it from top you will see they fit snug.

I believe this could be due normalizing, but i am not sure.

Comment: Try increasing the size of the geometry. I'm certain this is due to rounding errors because the float has too many decimal places(data is lost, or incorrectly interpreted along your pipeline.)

Comment: @Krythic i am not 100% sure what you mean by: "Try increasing the size of the geometry". Currently my Mesh size is 240x240 and i cannot increase that.

Comment: How large are your vertices? Are you cramming it all down into 0-1 range?

Comment: yes... they are all clamped betewwn 0 and 1

Comment: That's your problem. Some of them are probably 0.00xxx which results in rounding errors.

Comment: Thanks, let me change some procedures, and i'll give an update.

Comment: So playing with geometry did not help :(. It ended being a simple math issue. If x = 120, i would take the first 40 points for my first tile, then from 41 - 80 for my next tile, then 81-120 for my third tile. It seems fine... but between x(40) and x(41) there is a gap, which i missed :(. If i take my tiles like this: 0-40 then 40-80, then 80-120 then the seems align. Now my only issue is to fix the normals of the shared vertices on 40 and 80 :).

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it, though. Sorry if my suggestion caused you more work; that was not my intention.